# storage gas refund, is gas only refunded when storage is completely deleted? What if a key / value in a mapping is deleted?

Tags: gas-refund

I have a which tracks ids for some structs for different users.

`mapping (address => uint[]) usersStuff`

This  mapping for each user can grow or shrink.

If it happens to shrink to 0 for a single user (i.e. with `delete usersStuff[msg.sender]` ) but the actual variable hasn't been deleted because `usersStuff` has data for other users, is there a gas refund?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, deleting a mapping entry results in a gas refund.